# Setting multiply cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, dynamics-crm

I have following code

```
var formatedData = JSON.parse(outParams["Result"]);
var clientData = JSON.parse(outParams["ClientGuids"]);

Cookies.remove("client");
Cookies.remove("result");

Cookies.set("result", JSON.stringify(formatedData));
Cookies.set("client", JSON.stringify(clientData));

var obj = Cookies.get("result");
var o = Cookies.get("client");
```

I get the value of a "client", but there is no "result" cookie. I'm using https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie lib. Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the content of your outParams ?

Comment: What does `console.log(clientData)` tell you? And are there any console errors?

Comment: It may be that the content is too long?

Comment: Can you try setting the cookie with simpler values? Try the code directly in the browser console.

Comment: outParams contents a string representation of JSON Array.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Is there any restriction for length? My value is pretty long.

Comment: Why not use localStorage, or sessionStorage instead of cookies?

Comment: @evolutionxbox thank you very much. sessionStorage is exactly what I need.